# spec: selector "exists" does not find pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following service where I want to select a pod from a label that `exists`.

But it does not work, do you know why?

Note: `mypod: exists` in the followin:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  labels:
    run: myservice
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    mypod: exists
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The pod that I am trying to select is listed `kubectl get pods --show-labels`:

```
NAME                                         READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       LABELS
mypod-5bf4c474c8-l6rr2                1/1       Running   0          32m       mypod=49c8b466-2fdd-4ea6-b799-bc60c259a8ec
```

I don't have controle over the uuid and I know there will be only one pod - that is why I am trying to use `exists`.

Also if you know, what happens if there is more than one?

But most important, why does it not find the pod with `exists`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Michael Hausenblas answer.

Kubernetes is using 2 types of [labels selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) - `Set-based` and `Equality-based`.

Because the `Service` object is old and was created before `Set-based` requirements were released, you cannot use rules like `if label 'myapp' exists`, you should use equals like `if label 'myapp' = 'abc'`.

So, if your CI/CD is changing the value of `myapp` label, you can add some additional one with a static value, like `appname: myapp` and use it in the `Service` selectors. There are no other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your `kubectl` command output, the value of the label with the key `mypod` is in fact `49c8b466-2fdd-4ea6-b799-bc60c259a8ec` and not `exists`. So I suppose your CI/CD pipeline overwrites this? Anyways, a simple key-only query like `kubectl get po -l=mypod` should work.